# Reason for leaving the loop without terminating its condition in php

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop, conditional-statements

My code snippet is similar to the one below, but it goes out of the loop after about 250 to 330 rounds.

 Note: My array consists of 20 columns and 1000 rows.

```
<?php

for( $i = 1; $i <= $arrLen; $i++) {

    $personcode1 = $array[$i][$S_personcode];
    $ezafnum1 = $array[$i][$S_ezafnum];
    $postname1 = $array[$i][$S_postname];
    $mamoriyat1 = $array[$i][$mamoriyat];

    $namevahed1 =$array[$i][$namevahed];
    $takhirtajil1 = $array[$i][$takhirtajil];
    $ezterari1 = $array[$i][$ezterari];
    $esteghaghi1 = $array[$i][$esteghaghi];
    $estelaji1 = $array[$i][$estelaji];
    $roz1 = $array[$i][$roz];
    $ezaf1 = $array[$i][$ezaf];

    if ( mysql_query("INSERT INTO `tb_excell_ezafkar`(`parid`, `personcode`, `takhirtajil`, `ezaf`, `roz`,  `ezterari`, `mamoriyat`, `esteghaghi`, `estelaji`)
     VALUES ('$idpar','$personcode1','$takhirtajil1','$ezaf1','$roz1','$ezterari1','$mamoriyat1','$esteghaghi1','$estelaji1')
     ")) { 
        echo "";
    } else {
        echo mysql_error();
    }

    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question to clarify what you're asking. Also, what is the desired behavior?

Comment: Is the issue that you are not iterating through the entire array? What value have you initialized $arrlen to? It is not completely clear what you are asking, and the code snippet seems to be missing a few key pieces of info.

Answer (score 0):

First you can simplify it to get :

```
<?php

for($array as $v) {
    if ( 
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO `tb_excell_ezafkar`(`parid`, `personcode`, `takhirtajil`, `ezaf`, `roz`,  `ezterari`, `mamoriyat`, `esteghaghi`, `estelaji`) 
        VALUES ('$idpar','$v[S_personcode]','$v[takhirtajil]','$v[ezaf]','$v[roz]','$v[ezterari]','$v[mamoriyat]','$v[esteghaghi]','$v[estelaji]')")
        ) 
    { 
        echo "";
    } else {
        echo mysql_error();
    }

}
```

Second, it seems you have an extra `}` at the end of your loop.

Third, if it goes out of the loop it's either because of two things :

- $arrLen or (the actual size of $array) is not what you think it is,
- An error happened and stopped your loop, probably an invalid value in the array.

Comment: thanks for your help.  <br/>
But  <br/>
First, the checked data is not a problem because it does not always stop at a record.  <br/>
Second, an error appears to have occurred from a source failure.  <br/>

By the way, this is because this is part of my complete code.  <br/>